# How to install vector using puppet

Tags: vector, puppet

I'm trying to install vector (logging) using puppet but can't figure out how to specify the source and key for apt::source installation. Or where to get the source and key.

The vector install instructions for Ubuntu use an interactive script but I prefer not to run that using puppet exec.

The installation script includes these commands.

```
local gpg_keyring_path="/usr/share/keyrings/timber-vector-archive-keyring.gpg"
    curl -1sLf "https://repositories.timber.io/public/vector/gpg.3543DB2D0A2BC4B8.key" | gpg --dearmor > $gpg_keyring_path
```

How can I translate that into puppet?

Comment: Did you try `apt::key {'1E46C153E9EFA24018C36F753543DB2D0A2BC4B8':
  source => 'https://repositories.timber.io/public/vector/gpg.3543DB2D0A2BC4B8.key',
  id     => '1E46C153E9EFA24018C36F753543DB2D0A2BC4B8'
}`?

Comment: please write this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the key like this:

```
apt::key {'1E46C153E9EFA24018C36F753543DB2D0A2BC4B8':
   source => 'https://repositories.timber.io/public/vector/gpg.3543DB2D0A2BC4B8.key',  
   id     => '1E46C153E9EFA24018C36F753543DB2D0A2BC4B8'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## possible solutions (some untested):

### 1 via official method

```
puppet module install vector
```

### 2 Follow from the github/repo guide

https://github.com/pulling-strings/puppet-vector

### 3 vector.dev's recommended method

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.vector.dev | bash
```

### 4 if you have docker module in puppet

```
docker pull timberio/vector:0.24.1-debian
```

Comment: The repo is very old and I'd prefer to use apt.